# Proving/disproving $\exists n {\in} \mathbb Z \;\forall k {\in} \mathbb Z \;\exists d {\in} \mathbb Z \;\;k+ n = 2d$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am struggling to wrap my head around what this multiply quantified statement means:

$$\exists n {\in} \mathbb Z \quad \forall k {\in} \mathbb Z \quad \exists d {\in} \mathbb Z \quad k+ n = 2d.$$

Interpreting it as ‘There exists an integer $n$ which for all integers $k$ there exists another integer $d$ where $k+n=2d$’, I think it's true? Where to even begin to (dis)prove this statement?

Comment: Well, you can read "$\exists d \in \mathbb Z \; k+ n = 2d$" as "$k+n$ is even". Is that simpler to think about?

Comment: Yes, it does! So $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z},   n+k$ is even is clearly false. Thanks so much for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

> $\exists n {\in} \mathbb Z \quad \forall k {\in} \mathbb Z \quad \exists d {\in} \mathbb Z \quad k+ n = 2d.$
>
> Interpreting it as ‘There exists an integer $n$ which for all integers $k$ there exists another integer $d$ where $k+n=2d$’

Your interpretation is correct. Its negation says that there is some integer $k_n$ such that whatever integer $d$ is, $$k_n\ne2d-n.$$ Putting $k_n:=n+1$ shows that its negation is true.